# Number of gamertags in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print the total number of gamertags in a table which equals the rows.

```
$total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gamertags');
print $total;
```

The code above prints this idk why?

```
Resource id #3
```

Comment: Because you were too lazy to read just **ONE** page in manual: http://ru.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: I still don't get what you are refering to this is my first time with sql

Comment: open the given link and **do read** it.

Comment: mysql_query runs the query and returns the resource, then you have to pass the resource to a function to retrieve the data; as it says in the manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other guys, it's all explained on [that page](http://ru.php.net/mysql_query). But here's the answer anyway...

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gamertags');
$total = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's returning a mysql result variable. You can access the actual data with [mysql_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM gamertags');
$total = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $total;
```

Comment: As the name suggests, that will return an array, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

lol everyone is so critical...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM gamertags");
$resultsArray = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $resultsArray["number"];
```

mysql_fetch_array() will take a mysql resource and parse it into an indexed array and an associative array.

```
array(
      [0] => <number>,
      [number] => <number>
     )
```

mysql_fetch_assoc() will take a mysql resource and put it into an associative array only.

```
array(
       [number] => <number>
     )
```